# Edit Paypal's Return to Merchant link

Tags: paypal, hyperlink, return, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce with PayPal Standard as my shopping cart on a WordPress site. When a user purchases through PayPal, there is a 'Return to Merchant' link that the user has to click in order to get back to my website. It currently has my PayPal email address as the link, which is very confusing, as a user wouldn't think to click "Return to [email address]" in order to get back to a website. How can I make that link text the 'name of my website' instead of my email address?

I have "Auto Return" turned on with a web page specified in my PayPal Website Payment Preferences. However, it doesn't seem to auto return, leaving me with this merchant return link that isn't intuitive to click. I'm using the Sandbox to test the payment process...don't know if that makes a difference to this problem.

I'm assuming that the settings to change this link text are in PayPal and not in WooCommerce (couldn't find anything at all like that in my WooCommerce settings). If it is a WooCommerce issue, I will post on the appropriate forum. Thought I'd try PayPal first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no setting to alter the return link on the hosted page.

One of the limitations of the auto return feature is that if both the "auto return" and "account optional" features are turned on, customers who don't log in to PayPal can choose to go back to your website after checkout (using the link), but aren’t returned automatically.

You can navigate to either of these features on the "Website Preferences" page and click "Learn More" to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I will add instructions earlier on in the cart process to explain to users how to get back. Happy to know that I wasn't simply overlooking the answer in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

In sandbox mode it seams to display your email address.  Turning off sandbox mode you should see your business name now.